# check if estimation is unbiased?

Tags: statistics, parameter-estimation

Assume we that we calculate the expected value of some measurements $x=\dfrac {x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + x_4} 4$. what if we dont include $x_3$ and $x_4$, but instead we use $x_2$ as $x_3$ and $x_4$. Then We get the following expression $v=\dfrac {x_1 + x_2 + x_2 + x_2} 4$.

How do I know if $v$ is a unbiased estimation of $x$?

I am not sure how to approach this problem, any ideas are appreciated!

Comment: So $v$ is the same thing as $x$?  If that's not what you meant, then you need to clarify your question.

Comment: I assumed here that $x_k$ are random variables.

Comment: x is expected value of a random variable

Comment: (x1+x2+x3+x4)/4 calculates the expected value if a random variable has exactly four, equiprobable possible outcomes x1, x2, ..., x4. Alternatively, if x_1, x_2, ... x_4 denote 4 independent draws form some probability distribution, then (x1+x2+x3+x4)/4 is an *estimator* of the expected value, but it is *not* the actual expected value! To be precise, this is an important distinction.

Answer (score 0):

[EDIT: Assumed $x_k$ are random variables.]

We say $v$ is an estimator of random variable $x$ if $E[v]=E[x]$, where $E[\cdot]$ is expectation of random variables.

Recall that expectation is a linear operator, i.e. if $X$ and $Y$ are random variables and $a,b$ are constants, $E[aX+bY]=aE[X]+bE[Y]$. So we get $E[x]=\frac{1}{4}(E[x_1]+E[x_2]+E[x_3]+E[x_4])$, and $E[v]=\frac{1}{4}(E[x_1]+3E[x_2])$. Notice that $E[x]=E[v]$ is equivalent to $E[x]-E[v]=0$.

So $v$ is an unbiased estimator if $E[x]-E[v]=0 \Leftrightarrow E[x_3]+E[x_4]-2E[x_2]=0.$

Comment: How do we decide if $v$  is unbiased or not unbiased using $ E[x_3]+E[x_4]-2E[x_2]=0.$  as $x_2,x_3$ and $x_4$ are not defined?

Comment: What is this, if E[v] = E[x]?! Why are you taking expectations on the right hand side?

Comment: Almost certainly dumble24 is in a classical statistics environment and is estimating some parameter, not another random variable.

Comment: Edited the question, added some more context.

Answer (score 0):

Let $\theta$ be some parameter. Let $X$ be an estimator.

$X$ is called an unbiased estimator for $\theta$ if $E[X] = \theta$.

Note that $X$ is a random variable (or random vector) while $\theta$ would be a scalar (or vector).

#### Example

Let's say $x_1$ and $x_2$ are random variables with $E[x_1] = E[x_2] = \mu$. Then estimator $y = \frac{1}{5} x_1 + \frac{4}{5} x_2$ would be an unbiased estimate of $\mu$ since $E[y] = \mu$.

Comment: Whoever modded this down was either sloppy or doesn't know what he/she is talking about.